# css is not running while running requestDispatcher

Tags: html, css, jsp, requestdispatcher

i have a profile page and in that i have included a master page `welcome.jsp` . when i go to the profile page the CSS for the welcome page template is running fine but as i update the user,  the user is updated correctly and `requestDispatcher` is running fine but the CSS for the `welcome.jsp` is not running fine

code: `profile.jsp`

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Profile Page</title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
  <script>
     <jquery code>
  </script>  
</head>
<body>
    <%@ include file="welcome.jsp"%>

<center><h1>User Profile</h1></center><br><br>

<form action="/devilmaycry/register?action=updateuser" method="post">
   <html code>
</form>

</body>
</html>

  `request dispatcher code`

          rd=req.getRequestDispatcher("/Register/profile.jsp");  
          rd.include(req, res);
          pw.println("<h3>Record Updated !!!<h3>");
```

can someone tell me why the CSS gets disabled

cant post images because of low reputation :(

Comment: This is likely a pathing issue to the css file contained within the include.   double check your paths.

Comment: yes i found that that a min ago and answered the ques myself

Answer (score 0):

the path i gave for CSS file was `relative` , so when the requestDispatcher ran it changed the directory so the relative path didnt work

resolution --> always try to give `absolute` path to external files( .css , .jsp etc)